# How Do I Keep Total Time with Multiple Duplicate Entries?

Tags: python

I will attach my code, but basically I am importing a csv file with start times/end times for picking cases of a particular item. All the cases go to a "cart", which is identified by an ID number. I want to find the total time to pick all the cases. The format of the time is hh:mm:ss and, initially, I was using the datetime module but I could not figure out the documentation, so I ended up just converting all the times to seconds, subtracting end/start for each case, and adding that duration to the total time. In the end, converted total time to hours. Already had number of cases picked total, and divided by total time in hrs to get cases picked per hr. Is this correct logic? I got a number that was very, very low: 7.99 cases/hr, which leads me to believe my timing/duration code is incorrect (already checked that quantity was correct).

```
#instantiate totalTime to zero
totalTime = 0

#every line/row in file; assume already opened above
for line in lines:

    #if there is a different case to pick, find the start time
    if taskId != entryList[0]: #this is so it doesnt duplicate times

        timestart = entryList[7]
        colonStartIndex = timestart.find(":")
        hourstart = int(timestart[0:colonStartIndex])
        minutestart = int(timestart[colonStartIndex+1:colonStartIndex+3])
        colonStartIndex2 = timestart.find(":", colonStartIndex+1)
        secondstart = int(timestart[colonStartIndex2 +1:colonStartIndex2 +3])
        start = hourstart*3600 + minutestart*60 + secondstart

        #start = datetime(year=1, month=1, day=1,hour=hourstart,minute=minutestart,second=secondstart)
        #start = datetime.time(start)

        timeend = entryList[9]
        colonEndIndex = timeend.find(":")
        hourend = int(timeend[0:colonEndIndex])
        minuteend = int(timeend[colonEndIndex+1:colonEndIndex+3])
        colonEndIndex2 = timeend.find(":", colonEndIndex+1)
        secondend = int(timeend[colonEndIndex2+1:colonEndIndex2+3])
        end = hourend*3600 + minuteend*60 + secondend

        #end = datetime(year=1,month=1,day=1,hour=hourend,minute=minuteend,second=secondend)
        #end = datetime.time(end)
        #duration = datetime.combine(date.today(), end) - datetime.combine(date.today(), start)

        duration = end - start
        if duration >= 0:
            duration = duration
        elif duration < 0:
            duration = -1*duration
        totalTime = totalTime + duration
        taskId = entryList[0] #first entry in csv file of each line is cartID



totalTime = totalTime/3600
print(totalTime)
print(quantityCount)
avgNumCases = quantityCount/totalTime
print(avgNumCases)
```

Thank you so much for any help!! Also, I included the datetime stuff, commented out, so if you could suggest a solution based on that, I am open to it:) I was just frustrated because I spent a good bit of time trying to figure it out, but I'm not super familiar w it and the documentation is pretty hard to understand (esp b/c datetime objects, blah blah)

Answer (score 0):

There is an obvious problem in this section:

```
duration = end - start
if duration >= 0:
    duration = duration
elif duration < 0:
    duration = -1*duration
```

If your start point is 22:00:00 and end point is 21:00:00 your duration will be 1 hour instead of 23 hours.